# Change page, not navigate to new one

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got my first page, which asks for credentials. When login is successful, I'd like to change page, but in a way that BACK doesn't navigate to login page again, but out of application. How to achieve this? NavigateServices.Navigate just adds the new page to history stack.

Comment: NavigationService.GoBack(); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by removing an item from the back stack. In your "second" page override OnNavigatedTo and place the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationService.CanGoBack) NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```